# How can I directly upload smartphone videos to blog and comments?

Tags: uploads, mobile, videos

I am using MAMP and WordPress to locally host and test
my video website on my Macbook Air (using the templatic "video"
theme). I am trying to find the simplest way to easily upload and
embed videos (with the player visible and not just a link) taken from
my smartphone to my blog. I am also trying to find a way that
commenters can easily upload videos (and embed them so not just a link
to the video is present) from their smartphones (preferably directly)
to the comments of my blog.

Is there an easy way to do this (without first uploading the video to
youtube or another source)? The whole concept of the blog and comments
is to have video discussions (between me, the blogger, and commenters,
or also between various commenters) on a topic that are recorded on a
smartphone and uploaded easily onto the website.

I have been researching ideas and plugins for over a week. Any
suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Please note, as per the FAQ - we do not handle questions: that require professional hands-on involvement: i.e. overly complex and specific things (known as work for me for free) -- while you may get a helpful answer (I hope you do!) I had to down-vote this question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what type of smartphone but here is how I do it with my Iphone with the Wordpress app.

You can create a new post and add media to it by tapping the film strip icon and selecting the video you wish to upload. Now it will compress it and upload it to your wordpress install. If you view the post it will add it in a `<video>` container.

Now you can post it like a normal post and the video will display in the player and not as a link, no youtube needed.